# Wikipedia API query to return xml

Tags: python, xml, json, parsing, wikipedia-api

I'm trying to write myself a simple Python application to get a contents of a topic on Wikipedia. For instance as an example I'm trying to get the contents of the page on the fruit [apple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple) . This is my query:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=xml&titles=apple
```

This is what the output (formated) looks like:

http://pastebin.com/LNdDjXFj

But this doesn't really look like XML. It looks more like (I think) php. Should I just try to parse this with Python or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not PHP, it's media wiki formatting.

Look at the formatting mw page: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Parsing_wikitext

Personally, the json formatted version looks better to me (once it's parsed).

Comment: Yes, but even using action=parse doesn't give a different result. Does this mean I'll have to write a parser if I wanted to get just a particular section from each page? I was hoping that I can get a piece of text without all the wikipedia specific bit inside.

Comment: That's how the data is stored. There's a whole library of parsers out there. http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Alternative_parsers